# Eclipse Switch Button value Json url Read/Write

Tags: android, json, eclipse, switch-statement, outlet

```
{'outlet1':'on' , 'outlet2':'off' , 'outlet3':'on'}
```

[http://192.168.2.200:5555/getJsonData.json][1] in "Outlet1" provision on the value read out from the android buttons in the switch to the "ON" and "OFF" values ​​can be inflicted.

[image]

Comment: So what do you want to do?

Comment: "outlet2 = ON", I want to be switch button value "ON"

Comment: yourSwitch.setChecked(true);

Comment: I need help in Java code. I will use in home automation systems. I need to print on both json and read out. But somehow I could not.

Answer (score 0):

You can read json easily follow [this tutorial](https://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-json-parsing-url-example.html)
when its come to writing it's easy to generate and upload json but you need to commit it from serverside using a simple service

Comment: I tried, but the http address and value in the JSON key value read and the buttons do not operate. Http adress "Content-type application/json". Eclipse android information very weak, can you help?

Answer (score 0):

I also want to do the following operation android :

`<script> function updateControls() { $.getJSON('/status.json', function (json) { $.each(json, function (key, value) { $('#' + key).val(value).slider('refresh'); }); }); } $('select').on('change', function (event) { element = event.target.id; if (element.substr(0, 6) == 'outlet') { eleid = element.substr(6, 2); } else { eleid = 0; } command = event.target.value; $.get('/cmd', { 'eleid': eleid, 'cmd': command }); }); $(document).ready(function () { updateControls(); }); </script>`

Answer (score 0):

**Json managed to read. But Switch ON or OFF manually when I want to send a POST.**

```
Switch = ON  [POST value : http://192.168.2.200/State?eleid=10&cmd=on  ]
Switch = OFF [POST value : http://192.168.2.200/State?eleid=10&cmd=off ]
```